com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key key0 from store toDerInputStream rejects tag type -90
Getting below error while signing the release apk with correct keystore passwords.

com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key key0 from store "D:\Path_TO_keystore\file.jks": toDerInputStream rejects tag type -90

How to tackle this problem?
Error screenshot

Tried with another newly created keystore, it's working fine.
Expect to work with same keystore which I was working earlier, but unfortunately I am getting above error message.

After spending couple of hours got the exact root cause of this problem.
Actually, the keystore was corrupted while code transfer. And problem is resolved after the replacing the original keystore file in the same folder (D:\Path_TO_keystore<replaced_file>).
Keystore_filename, Keystore-password, KeyAlias & KeyAlias-Password would remain same.
I hope it will helpful someone, if they encounter same issue. Thanks!
